# Wordpress site has a lot of connections

Tags: mysql, linux, php, wordpress

Recently my wordpress site is having troubles and is stopping from working due to heavy load in the mysql processes. I need to know what is causing all this traffic and how to narrow the issue so I can troubleshoot the error. I ran some commands and I am getting this results

```
show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 143   |
| Connections              | 17736 |
| Max_used_connections     | 198   |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 6     |
+--------------------------+-------+

mysqladmin status
Uptime: 3711  Threads: 3  Questions: 17872313  Slow queries: 13  Opens: 344
     Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 335  Queries per second avg: 4816.036
```

and sometimes the cpu consumption by mysql reaches the 300%

Answer (score 0):

- 5 Connections/sec is slightly high.
- 5K QPS is high.
- Max_used_connections is already very high.  Part of this could be due to nothing being cached in the buffer_pool after the restart, which was barely an hour ago.  What is `Max_connections`?
- Aborted_connects/sec is quite high -- which is what you are asking about.  On the other hand, Aborted_connects/Connections is moderately high.  Any chance a hacker is trying to get in?
- If some of those 'slow' queries run a long time and/or block other actions, that could explain some of the issues.  What is `long_query_time`?  (It defaults to a virtually-useless 10 seconds; change it to 1.)  Are the slow queries being logged?  300% CPU *usually* indicates inefficient queries (indexing, formulation, etc)

Recommendations:

- Turn on the slowlog.
- Run for several hours before analyzing.
- Digest the slowlog to see what is naughtiest.
- See which of these you would like to pursue:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis